# How do I retrieve from a nested data structure a flat array of specific property values based on a predicate / condition?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, filter, mapping, reduce

I have this array of objects

```
[{
  id: 1,
  checked: true,
  subChild: [{
    id: 11,
    checked: true
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  checked: true,
  subChild: [{
    id: 22,
    checked: false
  }]
}, {
  id: 3,
  checked: false,
  subChild: [{
    id: 33,
    checked: true
  }]
}]
```

Is there any lib to get an item's `id` value based on its `checked` property? I could iterate the data-structure by `filter` and `find` but it would be a lot of manual work; ... imagine I have another level of nested arrays of objects.

The expected output for the provided sample data is `[1, 11, 2, 33]`.

Comment: Will the `subChild` always have only one or it might have multiple? Also, will the `subChild` have recursive `subChild`?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman for now one.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen included that. Maybe it's a good idea to flatten the array first.

Comment: @AliciaY Flattening this array might not be giving you expected results.

Comment: @AliciaY Check out my attempt. Hope it helps. It may not be the same order though.

Comment: How about a flat object that holds all the checked items. On selection, just set it in this object. `{ [key: id]: boolean }`. Then all you need is a single loop to check value. You can even optimize by just storing checked ids. That way, `Object.keys(checkedMap)` will give you the same output

Comment: @AliciaY ... _"imagine I have another level of nested array of object."_ ... Does the OP ask for a recursive approach which is capable of processing deeper nested structures of the form `[{ id: 1, checked: true, subChild: [{ id: 11, checked: true, subChild: [{ id: 111, checked: true/*, subChild: [ ... ] */ }] }] }`?

Comment: @AliciaY ... I meanwhile provided a recursive approach for fractal-like deeper nested `item/subChild` structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a `flatMap` to bring `subChild` objects to the parent array, then `filter` based on `checked` property and do a final `map` to get the `id`s.

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    checked: true,
    subChild: [
      {
        id: 11,
        checked: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    checked: true,
    subChild: [
      {
        id: 22,
        checked: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    checked: false,
    subChild: [
      {
        id: 33,
        checked: true,
      },
    ],
  },
];

let result = items
  .flatMap(({ subChild, ...item }) => [item, ...subChild])
  .filter((item) => item.checked)
  .map((item) => item.id);
  
console.log(result)
```

Comment: this is neat with flatMap

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sampleData = [{
  id: 1, checked: true,
  subChild: [{
    id: 11, checked: true,
    subChild: [{
      id: 111, checked: false,
      subChild: [{
        id: 1111, checked: true,
      }],
    }, {
      id: 112, checked: true,
      subChild: [],
    }],
  }],
}, {
  id: 2, checked: true, subChild: [{ id: 22, checked: false }],
}, {
  id: 3, checked: false, subChild: [{ id: 33, checked: true }],
}];

// 1. flatMap the items recursively
const flatFunc = ({ subChild, ...item }) => [item].concat(
  Array.isArray(subChild) ? subChild.flatMap(flatFunc) : []
);
const flattenArray = sampleData.flatMap(flatFunc);
    
// 2. filter and map to get the result
const checkedIDs = flattenArray
  .filter(item => item.checked)
  .map(item => item.id);

console.log({ checkedIDs, flattenArray });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @AliciaY ... The OP might check out the so far 2nd recursive implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I will do this way. Get the `subChild` arrays to the parent one. That's technically flattening the array in a custom way and then do a filter on this.

```js
const subChildren = [];
const final = [
  ...arr.map(a => {
    subChildren.push(a.subChild);
    delete a.subChild;
    return a;
  }),
  ...subChildren.flat()
];

console.log(final);
```

Now that's the code that I'll make it even more better by using a filter.

```
final.filter(f => f.checked);
```

This will give me the array with objects. Now I just need to transform it to just `id`s.

```
final.filter(f => f.checked).map(f => f.id);
```

This will give me the required answer of:

```
[1, 2, 11, 33]
```

Here's the full snippet:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    checked: true,
    subChild: [
      {
        id: 11,
        checked: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    checked: true,
    subChild: [
      {
        id: 22,
        checked: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    checked: false,
    subChild: [
      {
        id: 33,
        checked: true
      }
    ]
  }
];
const subChildren = [];
const final = [
  ...arr.map(a => {
    subChildren.push(a.subChild);
    delete a.subChild;
    return a;
  }),
  ...subChildren.flat()
];

console.log(final.filter(f => f.checked).map(f => f.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT due to the OP's sentence ...***

> ***"imagine I have another level of nested array of object."***

From my above comment ...

> @AliciaY ... *"imagine I have another level of nested array of object."* ... Does the OP ask for a recursive approach which is capable of processing deeper nested structures of the form `[{ id: 1, checked: true, subChild: [{ id: 11, checked: true, subChild: [{ id: 111, checked: true/*, subChild: [ ... ] */ }] }] }`?

This scenario/case gets covered best by a recursive implementation of my firstly (and now beneath) provided `reduce` and `concat` only approach.

```js
function collectCheckedItemIdRecursively(
  result,
  { id, checked, subChild = [] },
) {
  return result.concat(  
    (checked && id || []),
    subChild
      .reduce(collectCheckedItemIdRecursively, [])
  );
}

const sampleData = [{
  id: 1, checked: true,
  subChild: [{
    id: 11, checked: true,
    subChild: [{
      id: 111, checked: false,
      subChild: [{
        id: 1111, checked: true,
      }],
    }, {
      id: 112, checked: true,
      subChild: [],
    }],
  }],
}, {
  id: 2, checked: true, subChild: [{ id: 22, checked: false }],
}, {
  id: 3, checked: false, subChild: [{ id: 33, checked: true }],
}];

console.log(
  'recursively implemented `reduce` and `concat` only approach ...',
  sampleData
    .reduce(collectCheckedItemIdRecursively, [])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit ... for the 2 level nested data structure like provided originally by the OP, I leave my before provided approaches ...***

OP's title/subject

> shortcut to retrieve array of object property in javascript

There are no shortcuts but different approaches/strategies like ...

- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) only, but twice (once nested),
- `reduce` and `concat` with nested [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),
- [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) with nested `filter` and `map`,
- `flatMap`, `filter` and `map` with [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const sampleData = [{
  id: 1, checked: true, subChild: [{ id: 11, checked: true }],
}, {
  id: 2, checked: true, subChild: [{ id: 22, checked: false }],
}, {
  id: 3, checked: false, subChild: [{ id: 33, checked: true }],
}];

console.log(
  'nested `reduce` and `concat` twice ...',
  sampleData
    .reduce((result, { id, checked, subChild }) =>
      result.concat(

        (checked && id || []),
        subChild
          .reduce((arr, { id, checked }) =>
            arr.concat(checked && id || []), []
          )
      ), [])
);
console.log(
  '`reduce` and `concat` with nested `filter` and `map` ...',
  sampleData
    .reduce((result, { id, checked, subChild }) =>
      result.concat(

        (checked && id || []),
        subChild
          .filter(({ checked }) => checked)
          .map(({ id }) => id)

      ), [])
);
console.log(
  '`flatMap` and `flat` with nested `filter` and `map` ...',
  sampleData
    .flatMap(({ id, checked, subChild }) => [

      (checked && id || []),
      subChild
        .filter(({ checked }) => checked)
        .map(({ id }) => id)

    ].flat())
);
console.log(
  '`flatMap`, `filter` and `map` with rest parameter- and spread-syntax ...',
  sampleData
    .flatMap(({ subChild, ...rest }) => [rest, ...subChild])
    .filter(({ checked }) => checked)
    .map(({ id }) => id)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you !!!

```
 const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    checked: true,
    subChild: [
      {
        id: 11,
        checked: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    checked: true,
    subChild: [
      {
        id: 22,
        checked: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    checked: false,
    subChild: [
      {
        id: 33,
        checked: true,
      },
    ],
  },
];

let result = array
  .flatMap(({ subChild, ...item }) => [item, ...subChild])
  .filter((item) => item.checked)
  .map((item) => item.id);
```